# Battle City (Tank) replica

Tags: javascript, game, html5, canvas, collision

I'm learning JS and Canvas. A friend of mine gave me the task to create a [Battle City](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjrpJ3nj_HpAhUSbq0KHbVQAxgQFjAKegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FBattle_City&usg=AOvVaw2YXuRsd1I0DiHW3qzExJCn) replica. I've already managed to make the map and the player to move. Nothing fancy just some squares with a color, I tried to replicate the first map:

[image]

My code currently creates the map using 26 x 26 little `square`s (I chosen that amount because there are 13 "cols" in the image above, but each brick col is destroyed partially by a certain amount per shot (if IRC that was about 2-4 shots in the original game), in my case that's 2 bullets, so 13x2 = 26), my player uses 2 x 2 which is not ideal, because it requires to check 2 blocks for every direction, if I wanted to use a bigger grid, the size of the player grid might increase as well, making the code unmaintainable, how could I improve this code in order to have my player a single entity instead of a 4-block entity?

I think my intersection logic is kind of rudimentary, is there a way to improve this as well?

And I also struggled a little bit with the map drawing, as it's drawn vertically so I had to change the `i` and `j` variables so that the map wouldn't be rotated 90 degrees, I'm also interested in other options to do this and not having to paint the map and player every time I move the player in one direction.

```js
const mapGrid = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  ];
  
const canvas = document.getElementById('map');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const width = 24;
const height = 24;

const Directions = {
  up: 1,
  left: 2,
  right: 3,
  down: 4,
};

Object.freeze(Directions);

const playerCoords = [
  mapGrid.length - 2, 8,
];

const goalCoords = [6, 12];

const toRelativeCoord = (fromCoord) => fromCoord * width;

const drawMap = () => {
  ctx.beginPath();

  for (let i = 0; i < mapGrid.length; i += 1) {
    for (let j = 0; j < mapGrid[i].length; j += 1) {
      switch (mapGrid[i][j]) {
        case 1: //Bricks
          ctx.fillStyle = '#993333';
          break;
        case 2: //Iron-Bricks
          ctx.fillStyle = '#C0C0C0';
          break;
        case 3: //Base
          ctx.fillStyle = '#CCCC99';
          break;
        case 4: //Player
          ctx.fillStyle = '#FFFF00';
          break;
        default: //Road
          ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
          break;
      }
      ctx.fillRect(j * width, i * height, width, height);
    }
  }
};

const drawPlayer = () => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FFFF00';
  ctx.fillRect(toRelativeCoord(playerCoords[1]),
    toRelativeCoord(playerCoords[0]), width * 2, height * 2);
};

const repaint = () => {
  drawMap();
  drawPlayer();
  if (hasReachedGoal()) {
    alert('Game Over')
  }
};

const isMapEdge = (x, y, direction) => {
  switch (direction) {
    case Directions.up:
      return x - 1 < 0;
    case Directions.left:
      return y - 1 < 0;
    case Directions.right:
      return y + 2 === mapGrid[0].length;
    default: // back
      return x + 2 === mapGrid.length;
  }
};

const upIsClear = (x, y) => {
  if (isMapEdge(x, y, Directions.up)) {
    return false;
  }
  return mapGrid[x - 1][y] === 0 && mapGrid[x - 1][y + 1] === 0;
};

const leftIsClear = (x, y) => {
  if (isMapEdge(x, y, Directions.left)) {
    return false;
  }
  return mapGrid[x][y - 1] === 0 && mapGrid[x + 1][y - 1] === 0;
};

const rightIsClear = (x, y) => {
  if (isMapEdge(x, y, Directions.right)) {
    return false;
  }
  return mapGrid[x][y + 2] === 0 && mapGrid[x + 1][y + 2] === 0;
};

const downIsClear = (x, y) => {
  if (isMapEdge(x, y, Directions.down)) {
    return false;
  }
  return mapGrid[x + 2][y] === 0 && mapGrid[x + 2][y + 1] === 0;
};

const moveUp = () => {
  if (upIsClear(playerCoords[0], playerCoords[1])) {
    playerCoords[0] -= 1;
    repaint();
  }
};

const moveLeft = () => {
  if (leftIsClear(playerCoords[0], playerCoords[1])) {
    playerCoords[1] -= 1;
    repaint();
  }
};

const moveRight = () => {
  if (rightIsClear(playerCoords[0], playerCoords[1])) {
    playerCoords[1] += 1;
    repaint();
  }
};

const moveDown = () => {
  if (downIsClear(playerCoords[0], playerCoords[1])) {
    playerCoords[0] += 1;
    repaint();
  }
};

const listenToEvents = () => {
  document.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'W' || event.key === 'w') {
      moveUp();
    } else if (event.key === 'A' || event.key === 'a') {
      moveLeft();
    } else if (event.key === 'S' || event.key === 's') {
      moveDown();
    } else if (event.key === 'D' || event.key === 'd') {
      moveRight();
    }
  });
};

const intersects = (coord1, coord2) => {
  return coord1 == coord2 || coord1 + 1 == coord2 || coord1 - 1 == coord2;
}

const hasReachedGoal = () => {
  if ((intersects(playerCoords[0], goalCoords[0])) && intersects(playerCoords[1], goalCoords[1]) ||
      (intersects(playerCoords[0], goalCoords[0])) && intersects(playerCoords[1] + 1, goalCoords[1]) ||
      (intersects(playerCoords[0] + 1, goalCoords[0])) && intersects(playerCoords[1], goalCoords[1]) ||
      (intersects(playerCoords[0] + 1, goalCoords[0])) && intersects(playerCoords[1] + 1, goalCoords[1])) {
        alert('Hey!')
  }
  return false;
}

/**
 * DEVELOPER NOTE
 * x = rows
 * y = columns
 *
 * 0, 0 = top left corner
*/

const initialize = () => {
  drawMap();
  drawPlayer();
  listenToEvents();
};

initialize();
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tank</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="map" width="624" height="624"></canvas>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

---

## Edit

I did some research on how to use classes, and I think the code is now more readable and more structured. I believe this is an improvement, but anyway I'd appreciate if someone could judge it with an expert and critic eye so that I can improve this code.

I'm still interested in how to paint the map horizontally instead of vertically, as currently I have to switch `X` and `Y` coords for some calculations.

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tank</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="map" width="624" height="624"></canvas>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cell.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="goal.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tank.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
</html>
```

**cell.js**

```
const CellTypes = {
    road: 0,
    bricks: 1,
    ironBricks: 2,
    base: 3,
    player: 4,
    goal: 5
}

class Cell {
    static cellWidth = 24;
    static cellHeight = 24;

    constructor(x, y, color, type) {
        this.color = color;
        this.type = type;
        this.width = Cell.cellWidth;
        this.height = Cell.cellHeight;
        this.x = x * this.width;
        this.y = y * this.height;
    }
}
```

**goal.js**

```
class Goal extends Cell {
    constructor(x, y, color) {
        super(x, y, color, CellTypes.goal);
        this.width = this.width * 2;
        this.height = this.height * 2;
    }
}
```

**tank.js**

```
const Directions = {
    up: 1,
    left: 2,
    right: 3,
    down: 4,
};

class Tank extends Cell {
    constructor(x, y, color) {
        super(x, y, color, CellTypes.player)
        this.direction = Directions.up;
        this.speed = 12;
        this.width = this.width * 2;
        this.height = this.height * 2;
    }

    moveUp() {
        this.y -= this.speed;
    }

    moveDown() {
        this.y += this.speed;
    }

    moveLeft() {
        this.x -= this.speed;
    }

    moveRight() {
        this.x += this.speed;
    }
}
```

**game.js**

```
let maze = {
    map: [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ],
    goals: {
        goalColor: '#34EB9E',
        coords: [
            [12, 4], [0, 0]
        ]
    }
}

let cells = new Array(maze.map.length);
let goals = new Array(maze.goals.coords.length);
//Player coords
let player = {
    x: 8,
    y: 24
}

const canvas = document.getElementById('map');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let tank = new Tank(player.x, player.y, '#FFFF00');;

const initialize = () => {
    configureMaze();
    repaint();
    listenToEvents();
}

//Sets the data as cells objects
const configureMaze = () => {
    for(let i = 0; i < maze.map.length; i++) {
        cells[i] = new Array(maze.map[i].length);
        for(let j = 0; j < maze.map[i].length; j++) {
            switch(maze.map[i][j]) {
                case 1:
                    cells[i][j] = new Cell(j, i, '#993333', CellTypes.bricks);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cells[i][j] = new Cell(j, i, '#C0C0C0', CellTypes.ironBricks);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cells[i][j] = new Cell(j, i, '#CCCC99', CellTypes.base);
                    break;
                default:
                    cells[i][j] = new Cell(j, i, '#000000', CellTypes.road);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

//Draws the maze based on the configuration
const drawMaze = () => {
    ctx.beginPath();

    cells.forEach(cellsArr => {
        cellsArr.forEach(cell => {
            ctx.fillStyle = cell.color;
            ctx.fillRect(cell.x, cell.y, cell.width, cell.height)
        })
    })
}

//Goals are where some powerups will be
const drawGoals = () => {
    let i = 0;
    maze.goals.coords.forEach(coord => {
        goals[i] = new Goal(coord[0], coord[1], '#34EB9E');
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = '#34EB9E';
        ctx.fillRect(goals[i].x, goals[i].y, goals[i].width, goals[i].height);
        i++;
    })
}

//Draws the player's tank
const drawPlayerTank = () => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = tank.color;
    ctx.fillRect(tank.x, tank.y, tank.width, tank.height);
}

//Repaints the UI
const repaint = () => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawMaze();
    drawGoals();
    drawPlayerTank();
}

//Checks if the tank is on the canvas limit
const isMapLimit = (direction) => {
    switch (direction) {
        case Directions.up:
            return tank.y - 1 < 0;
        case Directions.down:
            return tank.y + 1 >= toCanvasCoord(maze.map.length - 2, Cell.cellWidth);
        case Directions.left:
            return tank.x - 1 < 0;
        case Directions.right:
            return tank.x + 1 >= toCanvasCoord(maze.map[0].length - 2, Cell.cellHeight);
    }
}

//Transforms map coords to canvas coords
const toCanvasCoord = (coord, toValue) => {
    return coord * toValue;
}

//Transforms canvas coords to map coords
const toMapCoord = (coord, toValue) => {
    return Math.floor(coord / toValue);
}

//Checks for intersection of coords
const intersects = (x1, y1, x2, y2, width, height) => {
    return x1 + width > x2 && y1 + height > y2 && x1 < x2 + width && y1 < y2 + height;
}

//Checks if we're standing in any of the goals zones
const isGoal = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < goals.length; i++) {
        if (intersects(tank.x, tank.y, goals[i].x, goals[i].y, goals[i].width, goals[i].height)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//Checks if the cell that we're trying to move is a road cell
const isRoadCell = (direction) => {
    let xCoord1; //xCoord for the top left corner
    let yCoord1; //yCoord for the top left corner
    let xCoord2; //xCoord for the tank's width
    let yCoord2; //xCoord for the tank's height
    switch (direction) {
        case Directions.up:
            xCoord1 = toMapCoord(tank.x, Cell.cellWidth);
            yCoord1 = toMapCoord(tank.y - tank.speed, Cell.cellHeight);
            xCoord2 = toMapCoord(tank.x + tank.width - 1, Cell.cellWidth);
            yCoord2 = toMapCoord(tank.y - tank.speed, Cell.cellHeight);
            break;
        case Directions.down:
            xCoord1 = toMapCoord(tank.x, Cell.cellWidth);
            yCoord1 = toMapCoord(tank.y + tank.height, Cell.cellHeight);
            xCoord2 = toMapCoord(tank.x + tank.width - 1, Cell.cellWidth);
            yCoord2 = toMapCoord(tank.y + tank.height, Cell.cellHeight);
            break;
        case Directions.left:
            xCoord1 = toMapCoord(tank.x - tank.speed, Cell.cellWidth);
            yCoord1 = toMapCoord(tank.y, Cell.cellHeight);
            xCoord2 = toMapCoord(tank.x - tank.speed, Cell.cellWidth);
            yCoord2 = toMapCoord(tank.y + tank.height - 1, Cell.cellHeight);
            break;
        case Directions.right:
            xCoord1 = toMapCoord(tank.x + tank.width, Cell.cellWidth);
            yCoord1 = toMapCoord(tank.y, Cell.cellHeight);
            xCoord2 = toMapCoord(tank.x + tank.width, Cell.cellWidth);
            yCoord2 = toMapCoord(tank.y + tank.height - 1, Cell.cellHeight);
            break;
    }
    if (maze.map[yCoord1][xCoord1] === CellTypes.road && maze.map[yCoord2][xCoord2] === CellTypes.road) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//Listens to WASD key presses
const listenToEvents = () => {
    document.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
        if (event.key === 'W' || event.key === 'w') {
            tank.direction = Directions.up;
            if (!isMapLimit(tank.direction) && isRoadCell(tank.direction)) {
                tank.moveUp();
                repaint();
            }
        } else if (event.key === 'A' || event.key === 'a') {
            tank.direction = Directions.left;
            if (!isMapLimit(tank.direction) && isRoadCell(tank.direction)) {
                tank.moveLeft();
                repaint();
            }
        } else if (event.key === 'S' || event.key === 's') {
            tank.direction = Directions.down;
            if (!isMapLimit(tank.direction) && isRoadCell(tank.direction)) {
                tank.moveDown();
                repaint();
            }
        } else if (event.key === 'D' || event.key === 'd') {
            tank.direction = Directions.right;
            if (!isMapLimit(tank.direction) && isRoadCell(tank.direction)) {
                tank.moveRight();
                repaint();
            }
        }
        if (isGoal()) {
            alert('GOAL!')
        }
    });
}

initialize();
```

Answer (score 2):

### Intersection logic

For the intersection logic, maybe it would be appropriate to make a method on the cell class that would determine if another cell (e.g. tank) overlaps with it. Refer to [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/31564/120114) for inspiration.

### Review

Just as a POJO is created for the definition of `Directions` I'd recommend setting up a POJO for the colors used in `drawMap`. That way instead of using the `switch` statement, the code can check to see if the value exists as a key in the mapping and then set the value of `ctx.fillStyle` accordingly.

The keypress handler can be simplified using `event.key.toLowerString()`, as well as a mapping of keys to directions.

`hasReachedGoal` calls `alert`. Some users may have disabled alerts in a browser setting. It is better to use HTML5 [`<dialog>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) element - it allows more control over the style and doesn't block the browser. Bear in mind that it [isn't supported by IE and Safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog#Browser_compatibility) but [there is a polyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill)

In `game.js` the function `grawGoals()` uses `foreach` with a callback function that accepts `coord` as a parameter. Instead of manually setting and updating a counter variable i.e. `i` accept it as the second parameter because `forEach` passes three arguments<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Parameters)</sup>.

In the original code `mapGrid` is declared with `const`, yet in *game.js* the `maze` is declared with `let`. It is better to use `const` as a default and then when you determine re-assignment is needed switch to `let`. This helps avoid accidental re-assignment.

Comment: The color thing is a really good suggestion, I didn't think of it. Would you say it's better to change `Directions` map, to something like `up: 'W', ...`? Those `alerts` were just for testing purposes actually, but I didn't know the `<dialog>` element existed. Thank you for this really helpful answer. I'll leave the question open until the bounty expires just in case someone else can provide some extra points.